Why do we need Connected App ClientId and ClientSecret to get token for Username And Password flow, but those are not required for SOAP login?
Why do we need Connected App ClientId and ClientSecret to get token for Username And Password flow, but those are not required for SOAP login?
Which are the uses cases to use the first over the second (which seems simpler) approach?

because one is an oAuth flow which dictates how it must work. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_disable_username_password_flow.htm&type=5 is a good read.

The protocol known as Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) is an XML-based standard that acts like a (Remote Procedure Call (RPC)), while all OAuth Flows are based on the OAuth2 REST-based protocol. In other words, the former doesn't require a Client Id or Client Secret because it's an entirely different protocol that actually predates OAuth by some time.
SOAP is used for languages/platforms that support SOAP. This includes older database systems, Java, PHP, etc that only support the older SOAP protocol. Newer platforms that support OAuth should consider using it, as it is much better in terms of security. For example, aside from OAuth username-password, all other flows never expose the username or password of the user to the client application, which reduces the risk of leaking passwords.
Note that the username-password flow is not meant for production. Once you're ready to go live, you should switch to an appropriate flow (web-server, user-client, etc) for your authentication. If you use the SOAP-based login model, you'll have to completely readjust your code for production if you want to use OAuth later.
